# Is it possible to bind a class type object to a reference through a non-type template parameter in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug, non-type-template-parameter

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct wrapper {
    int& ref;
    constexpr wrapper(int& ref) : ref(ref) {}
};

template <auto&& X>
void fun1() {}

template <wrapper X>
void fun2() {
    fun1<X>();
}

int main() {
    static int val = 22;
    fun2<val>();
}
```

`fun2<X>()` takes in a class as non-type template parameter while `fun1<X>()` takes in a forwarding reference to any object passed to it.

The above [fails to compile in GCC with the error shown below but compiles just fine in Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/q8sGae4qe).

```
<source>:11:12: error: the address of 'wrapper{val}' is not a valid template argument
   11 |     fun1<X>();
      |     ~~~~~~~^~
```

Which compiler is correct here? Is this supposed to be a bug in either of the two compilers?

I tried to change `template <wrapper X>` to `template <const wrapper& X>`, but to no avail, as it [fails on both GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/TG7rcxGG1).

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks for the heads up, I wasn't aware of that. I edited the error into the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid. This is possibly a GCC bug. I've submitted a bug report, see **[GCC Bug 113242 - g++ rejects-valid template argument of class type containing an lvalue reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113242)**.

> For a non-type *[template-parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#nt:template-parameter)* of reference or pointer type, or for each non-static data member of reference or pointer type in a non-type *[template-parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.param#nt:template-parameter)* of class type or subobject thereof, the reference or pointer value shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively):
>
> - a temporary object ([class.temporary]),
> - a string literal object ([lex.string]),
> - the result of a `typeid` expression ([expr.typeid]),
> - a predefined `__func__` variable ([dcl.fct.def.general]), or
> - a subobject ([intro.object]) of one of the above.

- [[temp.arg.nontype] p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.arg.nontype#3)

The reference `auto&& X` refers to an object `wrapper X` that is none of those, so it should be a valid template argument.

Note that what happens in `main` is effectively:

```cpp
int main() {
    static int val = 22;       // OK, obviously
    constexpr int& ref = val;  // OK, can bind reference to static storage duration object
    constexpr wrapper w = ref; // OK, can create object containing such reference
    fun2<w>();                 // OK, but GCC errors in fun2's definition
}
```

Also note that the [unqualified-id](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.unqual#nt:unqualified-id) `X` in `fun1<X>()` is an lvalue of type `const wrapper` ([[expr.prim.id.unqual] p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id.unqual#2)).
Therefore, the reference binding is direct and no temporaries are involved.

### Second Example

Both compilers are correct in rejecting

> ```cpp
> template <const wrapper& X>
> void fun2() { /* ... */ }
>
> int main() {
>     static int val = 22;
>     fun2<val>();
> }
> ```

... because `fun2<val>()` makes `X` bind to a temporary `wrapper` object, created within the function call to `fun2`.